# SQL Select from one table twice field related to single table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 table

```
--------------------------------------------
TABLE 1:
ID
DUREE_FREQ_ID => foreign key idFrequence
POSOL_FREQ_ID => foreign key idFrequence
INTER
------------------------------------------
TABLE 2:
idFrequence
libFrequence
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to make a  query to get `libFrequence` for `DUREE_FREQ_ID` and `POSOL_FREQ_ID` at the same time!

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.duree_freq_id,
  td.libfrequence AS duree_freq,
  t1.posol_freq_id,
  tp.libfrequence AS posol_freq
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 td ON (td.idfrequence = t1.duree_freq_id)
LEFT JOIN table2 tp ON (tp.idfrequence = t1.posol_freq_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Table1.*, t2a.libFrequence AS DUREElib, t2b.libFrequence AS POSOLlib
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2a ON Table1.DUREE_FREQ_ID = t2a.idFrequence
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2b ON Table1.POSOL_FREQ_ID = t2b.idFrequence
```

Comment: get the same value for the 2 fields :(

Comment: You will have to show a sample of the data you are talking about for me to tell you why that is happening

Comment: it shows me error on xsd interface but it works on the front end you just save my life :D